# many-to-many persistence

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jsf-2, persistence

I am new to Java EE, and I set up a learning case for myself where I can register users and persist the data to the database, I use Glassfish, EclipseLink JPA 2.0 and JSF framework. The database  contains three tables: user(id[pk],name,gender,...), hobby(id[pk],hobby_name), and user_hobby which describes the many-to-many relationship and contains only user_id and hobby_id.

in the User.java entity class, I declare the relationship as such:

```
...
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
    name="user_hobby",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="hobby_id")
)
private List<Hobby> hobbies;

public List<Hobby> getHobbies() {
    return hobbies;
}

public void setHobbies(List<Hobby> hobbies) {
    this.hobbies = hobbies;
}
...
```

and in the Hobby.java class, I declare bidirection as such:

```
...
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="hobbies",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<User> users;

public List<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}
...
```

In the JSF view page, I output all the hobbies from the hobby table which contain pre-inserted values like such:

```
<h:selectManyListbox id ="hobb" label="Hobbies" value="#{userController.user.hobbies}" >
      <f:selectItems value="#{itemController.hobbyItems}"/>
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

and corresponding itemcontroller has this method:

```
public List<SelectItem> getHobbyItems(){
    List<SelectItem> items=new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    //fetch all hobbies from database
    List<Hobby> hobbies=hobbyFacade.findAll();
    for(Hobby h:hobbies)items.add(new SelectItem(h,h.getHobby()));
    return items;
}
```

Here you can see that I inject a list of hobby objects into the view and let user.hobbies get hold on it.

When I create users, if I don't select hobbies, then the creation succeeds and data is persisted to the database, but if I select any hobby, the server throws a null pointer exception, which I couldn't figure out why, I have spend almost a day to debug this, but could not make any progress. Could anybody maybe help me with this issue, I would much appreciate it. If you need any more information about settings, please let me know.

Update exception(first three lines):

```
WARNING: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.checkForUnregisteredExistingObject(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:745)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.discoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4124)
```

Comment: The first line of the stack trace of the exception should tell you exactly at which line of code this exception happens. Showing us the stack trace would help us helping you.

Comment: hi, thanks for reply, actually, it does not specify why does the exception happen, just tell me nullpointerexception, please refer to the update.

Comment: From your stack trace the error is at `org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.checkForUnregisteredExistingObject(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:745)` unfortunately you haven't given enough lines to find out which part of your code causes that. Basically we need more of your stack trace, at least as far as the first line that starts with `at` followed by the fully qualified name of one of your classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a long struggling with this issues, I finally solved the problem. the problem was about conversion between string in view and object in backing bean. I used mapping solution which is one of the methods proposed in this post: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/09/objects-in-hselectonemenu.html. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please include your code to create  users that is failing and include the full exception stack trace.

Are you adding a null value to a list?

Ensure that you are using the managed versions of the objects and merging your objects correctly.